# How to exclude from OnMethodBoundaryAspect-based logging?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, postsharp, aop

I have this logger:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MethodsInterceptAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) { Logger.LogMethodEntry(args.Method, DateTime.Now); }
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args) { Logger.LogMethodExit(args.Method, DateTime.Now); }
}
```

But there's an intensive function (many nested loops, performance-critical) that also bloats the log. How do I exclude it and all its subroutines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `AttributeExclude=true` property of the aspect. The exclusion can be applied at the assembly level

```
[assembly: Trace("Business", AttributeTargetTypes="BusinessLayer.*", AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: Trace(AttributeTargetMembers="Dispose", AttributeExclude = true, AttributePriority = 2)]
```

or per method

```
[assembly: Trace("Business", AttributeTargetTypes="BusinessLayer.*")]
namespace BusinessLayer
{
  public class Process : IDisposable
  {
   public Customer Create(string value) { ... }
   public void Delete(long id) { ... }

   [Trace(AttributeExclude=true)]
   public void Dispose() { ... }
  }
}
```

[A more complete answer can be found here](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/multicasting-of-custom-attributes.aspx)

Comment: It took me a while to consider it, since my question was "...How do I exclude it and all its subroutines ?", emphasizing the last part: "...and all its subroutines ?". But it seems that there's no pure `AOP` or `PostSharp` way to do it..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be the automatic propagation you require.